# UICollectionViewCell Internal Padding (Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, padding, uicollectionviewcell

All the answers refer to `UICollectionView` padding. My question is about `UICollectionViewCell` padding. I want to be able to set a certain padding inside cell so that the contents of the cell will not touch the edge of the cells. Is there such a property?

Comment: Why not do it in the IB?

Comment: because I need to calculate that padding based upon screen size at run-time

Comment: So, in that particular `UICollectionViewCell `, I would have a simple view that acts as a container for every other subview . Then connect the leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to outlets, to manipulate their constants later in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Idea

So, in that particular `UICollectionViewCell`, I would have a simple view that acts as a container for every other subview. Then connect the leading, trailing, top, and bottom constraints to outlets, to manipulate their constants later in code.

### Method

[image]
[image]

### Result

[image]